# How can I update a wordpress plugin from a Git repository (github)

Tags: plugin-development, git

is there any way to easily update a plugin installed on multiple sites from a github repo. I know I can do it from the command line of each server using git pull. but is there a way to do it from the wordpress admin similar to how plugins are updated?

Comment: i imagine you could do this with the [github api](http://develop.github.com/). maybe have a look at [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/latest-github-commits/), which uses the api to grab some data from github.

Comment: thanks for the link. i'm just wondering if there is an easy way or an existing plugin. i'd rather not have to code it myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wrote a PHP class that allows a plugin developer to incorporate updates from GitHub within their plugin. Here's a link for it -> https://github.com/jkudish/WordPress-GitHub-Plugin-Updater

Comment: Do you need anything else about the class?

Answer (score 4):

Check out this plugin updater class for WordPress: https://github.com/jkudish/WordPress-GitHub-Plugin-Updater

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote up a post about [deploying an entire WordPress site](http://beacon.wharton.upenn.edu/davekonopka/2011/06/automating-wordpress-deployment-with-capistrano/) with a few custom plugins and theme to multiple servers using Capistrano. You could probably do the same for just the single plugin repo.

There's a bunch of good posts out there for the [step-by-step details on getting Capistrano going for WordPress](http://whomwah.com/2009/02/01/deploying-wordpress-to-slicehost-using-capistrano-and-git/).

Comment: Capistrano looks pretty cool, but not really what I'm after. I'm looking for something that will work from the wp admin. +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I eventually found was to use a deployment service such as http://deployhq.com and http://deploy.phpfog.com. The nice thing about these services is that you can easily rollback to any commit

Answer (score 0):

I used this plugin

https://wppusher.com/

It works fine,

Supports github, gitlab, bitbucket

Free for public repositories

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned in your comment that you are looking for an easy way and you'd rather not have to code it yourself I guess it is safe to recommend [WP Package Editor (WP2E)](https://wp2e.recuweb.com/) a SaaS providing a way to deploy and manage a set of interdependent Themes & Plugins from a single dashboard.

Among other things the service uses a registered GitHub App to pull the latest version from public / private GitHub repositories.

The part of the [documentation regarding GitHub implementation](https://wp2e.recuweb.com/docs/getting-started/wp-installer/upgrade-a-github-repo/) lists 4 conditions for a script to be successfully imported to the library of repositories and later be synchronized as an installer dependency:

1. The GitHub App must be connected to a WP2E account
2. The “read-only” access to the repository must be granted to the WP2E GitHub App
3. The script must be a valid WP theme or plugin
4. The repository must have at least one “release” on GitHub

You can also find more details about the registered app by visiting the Github Marketplace and look for the app of the same name:

- https://github.com/marketplace?type=apps&query=wordpress
- https://github.com/marketplace/wp-package-editor

> On a side note, the GitHub App *must* be integrated via the WP2E panel in order to
> synchronize with your account. If you setup the app directly via the
> GitHub Marketplace the service wont be able to reach it.